# MySQL - MATCH behaves as searching over a whole word only

Tags: mysql, match

I don' really get it, but my `MATCH (columnName) AGAINST ('word')` in MySQL only found those contain exactly `word`, but not `words` or `keyword`.

I tried running this query on my system:

```
select count(*) from content where lcase(content_text) like '%try%' 
and not match (content_text) against ('try') order by content_id
```

and I received result

```
| count(*) |
____________
|  379     |
```

which I believe should be 0. What could go wrong with my query or database?

PS: table `content` is MyISAM and I have set column `content_text` full indexed.

Answer (score 2):

'try' is a MySQL stopword. For full-text search, the word is being ignored.

Reference: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/fulltext-stopwords.html

Also, yes you're right that `MATCH` only searches for whole word. It's a natural language search. If you prefer to search for partial word (characters within words), use `LIKE %xxx%` isntead.

Comment: Also, yup you're right that `MATCH` only searches for whole word. Use `LIKE %XXX%` if you want to search for characters within words.

Comment: that's very bad, using `LIKE %XXX%` is much slower :(

Comment: Yes, if possible try to avoid `LIKE %xxx%` queries. Even `LIKE xxx%` is a big improvement.

Answer (score 2):

Fulltext search stop some common word, but it is disable using this steps.

1: open my.ini file in mysql

2: place below two line after [mysqld] line in my.ini (search [mysqld] in file)

```
ft_min_word_len=1
ft_stopword_file=""
```

3: restart your server

4: repair your table using below command

> repair table tablename;

5: now your search is working....